# IIS web.config setting turns url in to parameter

Tags: iis

I did this on another project and now I can't make it work.

I need to set up the virtual address's in the web.config so that the URL

http://my.webspace.com/thesite/animal/dog/puppy

actualy goes to the page /thesite/animal.html with dog and puppy in the parameters.

Comment: What ASP.NET flavor did you use in that other project? ASP.NET MVP oder "classic" ASP.NET?

Comment: ASP.NET using IIS 6.0

When you set up the mapping for the virtual address in web.config you can specify that the last parts of it are actualy parameters.

Just can't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for an url rewriter.

There's an example implementation at MSDN; [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Comment: It does look like an HttoHandler is needed to do this.